# PHP value doesn't equal to what it echoes

Tags: php

I got a value in `$array[1]` and I want to know what it is, so I
can compare it in other parts of my code.

So I echo out $array[1] and I get "vrij &nbsp &nbsp " or "vrij     "

```
$value = $array[1];
echo $value ; // outputs "vrij     "
if($value = $array[1]){
    echo "TRUE 1";
} 
if($value = "vrij     "){ 
   echo "TRUE 2";
}
```

The problem is, it only echo's TRUE 1. I copy pasted the echo exactly but it doesn't return TRUE 2

Comment: do a `var_dump($value)` and `var_dump($array[1])`, which'll show off more details of the two variables (type + size + content).

Comment: There is a big difference between &nbsp; values and an actual space, I would think that is causing your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You're assigning the value of `$array[1]` to `$value`, not comparing them. Change the `=` into `==` inside the if clauses.

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't make a difference. I think it is because the spaces are converted to special characters or something....  Thanks anyway

Comment: I second this, although it's still strange that the second TRUE 2 is not displayed because "vrij    " will be regarded as TRUE when treated as bool.

Comment: Try `echo "<pre>'$value'</pre>";` and count the spaces.

Comment: Also this is why good coding standards generally recommend putting the variable behind the operator (like "vrij " == $value) to prevent these accidental(?) mistakes.

Comment: Thank you, it was 5 spaces and two enters in the end. Took me 2 days to figure out hahah. Thanks again :)